# Why does mod_tile have a limit of 10 XML files?

Tags: mod-tile

I recently discovered that mod_tile does not, by default, allow more than 10 XML configs to be specified in `renderd.conf`. Upon closer inspection, I found that I could change that limit in [here](https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile/blob/master/includes/render_config.h) by setting `XMLCONFIGS_MAX` to a different value, and then recompiling. I also found that a value larger than ~300 will segfault renderd when started.

Is there a reason this limit is so low? Is it related to renderd crashing with a high XML config count?